# Angular 1.2.28 not working in IE9 with nginx server

Tags: angularjs, nginx, routes, internet-explorer-9, fragment

I faced with pretty interesting issue.
I'm developing an Angular application and it doesn't work in IE9. I figured out where is the problem.
An nginx server that serves the application in some cases sends different index.html files (using `try_files` directive) based on requested urls (using `location if` conditions) (also, note that different index.html has different Angular applications inside). So handling by url doesn't work for IE9 because IE9 doesn't support History API and it falls back for using hashes `#` and hash fragments are not sent to the server at all. How to fix this? Could you suggest a good way to serve different index.html for different url hash fragments in case of IE9?

Comment: Sounds like a design flaw in app. What is use case for sending different index files?

Comment: @charlietfl Separating authorization process from the main app.

Comment: Well with hash in url there is only one entry point so you would need to reconfigure auth process based on that